# display grid view of different model yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2

I need to display grid view in index page that  include attribute of another model.

I need to get data from model that not in current model.

I'm new to yii2 framework please explain the process step by step.

Comment: Do you already have one gridView in that action, and want to add another?

Comment: yes i need to add another using different table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show two gridview in a view you need to insert the the two separated gridview with different dataprovider (eg. $dataProvider1, $dataProvider2)  and in the action  :

```
    return $this->render('yourView', [
        'searchModel1' => $searchModel1,
        'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,
        'dataProvider1' => $dataProvider1,
        'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,
    ]);
```